# How to selected parent category in select box in admin_edit.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

How to selected parent category in select box in admin_edit.ctp

Categories table stuture

```
ID Name ParentID
1  Parent1  0
2  Parent2  0
3  Child1   1
4  Child2   1
5  Child3   2
6  Child4   1
```

Category.php(model)

```
 var $belongsTo = array(
        'ParentGroup' => 
            array('className' => 'Category', 
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
        ), 
     ); 


   var $hasMany = array( 
    'ChildGroup' => 
            array('className' => 'Category', 
                  'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
            ), 
    );
```

admin_edit.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Category'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("id" ,array('type' => 'hidden', 'label' => false,'div' => false))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("parent_id" ,array('label' => false,'div' => false,'class'=>"text-field" ))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("category" ,array('label' => false,'div' => false,'class'=>"text-field" ))?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('edit'); ?>
```

noting data showing in parent_id select box

Answer (score 0):

```
//Controller
$categories = $this->Category->find('list', array('conditions'=>array(all your conditions)));
$this->set('categories', $categories);

//View    
$this->Form->input('category_id');
//you can set the type if it doen't work
$this->Form->input('category_id', array('type'=>''));
```

[Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs)

you put both of the association of parent, child into one Model,

that belongs_to has to be inside the child Model

parent model and has_many should go inside the parent

```
//Category Model
     var $belongsTo = array(
            'ChildGroup' => 
                array('className' => 'ChildGroup', 
                      'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
            ), 
         ); 

//Child Model    
       var $hasMany = array( 
        'ParentGroup' => 
                array('className' => 'ParentGroup', 
                      'foreignKey' => 'parent_id' 
                ), 
        );
```

read this article for model association  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html  and usetable if your table name if different from your model name http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

Comment: but how to selected parent category correspondence child category?

Comment: you can you contain behavior | conditions if your are sre your model is associated properly

Comment: but me that error Error: Table child_groups for model ChildGroup was not found in datasource default

Comment: did you assign name of the model on top of each model? and also if name of tables are different from model name it gives you this error

Comment: you mean to say like that  var $name = 'ChildGroup'; or wht?

Comment: read this article for model association  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html  and usetable if your table name if different from your model name http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html